# How to fix 413 HTTP Request entity too large

Tags: angularjs, scala, http, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a project where I have a simple client written in angularjs and the server is in scala, in my client I have a simple upload button where you click on it and choose a local file(csv), and when I upload a certain csv that is a bit big, like 6000 rows I get

> 413 Request entity too large

my js code for the upload is:

```
 $scope.upload = function(files) {
    if (!files || !files.length) {
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        Upload.upload({
            url: '/uploadFile',
            file: file
        }).
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.showServerError(status, data);
        })
      }
    }
  };
```

in the server is :

```
def uploadFile = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>

    request.body.file("file").fold {
      BadRequest("Missing file")
    } { uploadedFile => {

      val localFile = new File("/tmp/" + uploadedFile.ref.file.getName)

      Files.copy(uploadedFile.ref.file.toPath, localFile.toPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
      localFile.deleteOnExit()
      val j = Json.parse( ${Crypto.encryptAES(localFile.getAbsolutePath)}})
      Ok(j)
    }}
  }
```

what needs to be change in order to support bigger files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`maxLength`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse) body parser to specify the maximum size of the body in bytes:

```
// Allow up to 15MB files...
private val uploadParser = parse.maxLength(15*1024*1024, parse.multipartFormData)

def uploadFile = Action(uploadParser) { implicit request =>
  ...
}
```

The default is 10MB for multipart form data, which you can also override by changing the `play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer` setting. See the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Max-content-length).

Comment: I have tried to set play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=20M cause I want to support uploads up to 20 mb and it didnt work...do you know why? am I writing it ok?

Comment: @jackmiao did you try changing **`maxDiskBuffer`**?

Comment: yes...this is what is what i did `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=20M` in application.conf

Comment: **Disk**, not memory: `play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=20M` ;-)